# How to implement a preloader with jQuery deferred objects

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm using jQuery deferred objects so I can pull data from multiple sources , however not sure how best to code in a loading message that displays whilst everything is being resolved and then hides when everything is resolved OR rejected

CURRENT CODE:

```
 jQuery.when(loadData('ws-get-shops.php', {shopId:123}),loadData('ws-get-customers.php')).then(updateResults,showError);


var loadData = function(url, data){

    var jqxhr = jQuery.ajax({
        url:url,
        data:data,
        dataType:'jsonp',
        timeout:60000
    });

    return jqxhr;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add (or show) the loading message right before you start the ajax calls, like:

```
$('#loadingMsg').show();
jQuery.when(...).then(updateResults,showError);
```

and then delete (or hide) it in the `updateResults` and `showError` function when they finish, like:

```
function updateResults(...) {
    $('$#loadingMsg').hide();
    ...
}

function showError(...) {
    $('$#loadingMsg').hide();
    ...
}
```

You can also add another function as the third parameter to the `then` function which is called when the `when` function makes progress and update your loading message to show a percentage or something.

Reference: http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/